# Razor Page Unable to Call Service Method CS0120

Tags: c#, web-services, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I am using the service ITADService with the following method:

```
public async Task GetAllGames()
{
var result = InterpretStringResponse((await _http.GetAsync("api/itad")).ToString());
}
```

My razor page calls this method with:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await ITADService.GetAllGames();    
}
```

This leads to the CS0120 build-time error stating that an object reference is necessary, yet when I create an instance of the service on the page with:

```
private readonly HttpClient _http;
ITADService service = new ITADService(_http);
```

Visual Studio tells me that an initializer cannot reference it if it isn't static.

How is this supposed to be done? Is the error in the service or the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is this supposed to be done?

1. Register the ITADService in Program.cs
   `builder.Services.RegisterScoped<ITADService>();`
2. Inject the HttpClient in the constructor of ITADService
   `public ITADService(HttpClient http) { _http = http; }`
3. Inject ITADService into your page
   `@inject ITADService iTADService`

Comment: Is there a difference between `services.RegisterScoped<ITADService>();` and `builder.Services.AddScoped<IITADService, ITADService>();`? Because VS says that `'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition` for it. I hope using `new` is fine.

Comment: `builder` or not depends on the version. Doesn't matter, look at the other Register* calls. And if you have the interface IITADService then yes, use it. You weren't using it in the question.  And no, new() is not fine.

Comment: Thanks, got it working and I'll take your word about not making a new HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

CodeCaster gave the solution in the comments:
Use an instance of ITADService:

```
ITADService service = new ITADService();
```

Change the constructor so that it takes no parameters, just:

```
public ITADService()
{
    _http = new HttpClient();
}
```

Then refer to the instance rather than the class itself in the call:

```
await service.GetAllGames();
```

Comment: Don't `new()` a HttpClient. Or any other service.